# Flight mechanics of a quadcopter, yaw, conservation of angular momentum, linear momentum counterpart?

Tags: kinematics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, rotation

I have been trying to understand how a quadcopter yaws. Referring to the figure below which is bird's eye view of a quadcopter:

[image]
image credit : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQAPkN7OWus

While the quadcopter is just hovering, the net angular momentum of the system is zero, since the angular momentums of motor set A and motor set B will be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction. So, far, so good.

If I increase rpm, so the angular velocity($\omega$) of the propellers, of the motor set B; then they will produce more(in magnitude) angular momentum w.r.t motor set A. So, the total angular momentum of the system will not remain at 0 but will increase towards upward(out of the page) direction. At this point, the phenomenon which causes quad to yaw comes into play, the quadcopter starts to rotate in the opposite direction of motor set B, i.e clockwise, to preserve previous net angular momentum of the system, which was 0. So, at this point, we call it *conservation of angular momentum* of the system.

**Am I consistent with the laws of physics so far?**

If I am, then, I get confused when I think the same conservation thing for linear momentum. So, we have our car at rest. So the initial linear momentum of the system is 0 since the speed is 0 ($v = 0$). Then we increase gas pedal, and car starts to move. So the final linear momentum of the car is not 0 anymore. But, why, something similar to the quad case does not happen? In that case, system was counteracting the change in the momentum. But our car just gained momentum.

I know this part sounds very silly, but, I think I have some misunderstandings somewhere. So, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember, the quadcopter is not operating in vacuum. Your question talks about the angular momentum of the rotors and, of the whole machine, but I don't see anywhere you talk about the angular momentum that the rotors transfer to the _air_ as they beat it down.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for answering, can you a bit more explain your point?

Comment: I don't think I can explain how quadcopters fly, And I'm not sure I understand your whole question, but you said, "...angular momentum of the system," without ever mentioning the air.  The air is part of "the system," and the column of air accelerated by an open propeller _rotates_: A propeller imparts angular momentum to the air mass that passes through it.